# Test/Test suite level reporter in playwright

Tags: testing, browser-automation, playwright

Is there is a way to setup multiple reporters for multiple test suites?

For example,
if I had a 2 test suites like A, B.
I want report needs to be generated for A in separate file and for B separate.

Especially i need custom reporter instead of HTML, JSON. By that based on that test suite result I need to update in status page of the application.

Is this possible with playwright or any other third-party test-reporters?

case:

I want to run tests based on some other test results. In order to workout this I need test results before tear-down like in custom-reporter.

workaround:

I had a workaround that by creating multiple configuration files.